# Looking up items from a structure in C?

Tags: c, structure

I have a list of names and associated test scores in a structure and I'm not sure how search names by inputting the score.

I'm using printf/scanf to take the input (score). Using the if, else if statement for each score works but it is too long.  I'm looking for a shorter method.

I'm new to C programming so please help me.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by shorter method? Shorter code implementation or faster implementation? If you want shorter code, at least post your implementation here; if you want faster implementation, I guess you have to optimize your data structure with some indexing technique.

Comment: Will you post your `structure` and how you are filling it with the names and scores? That will help insure you get a meaningful answer and prevent people from having to **guess** at your situation. Further, since the `scores` are most likely `floating point` numbers, so will be better served by bracketing the score you are searching from rather than looking for an exact match. See: [**The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know ...**](http://floating-point-gui.de/)